# Symfony 1.4.11 & Propel: time format problem in fixtures file

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, propel

I've got a problem:

I have a schema.yml which contains a field with the type "time":

```
time_space:          { type: time, required: true }
```

For my initial data, I have a fixture file which contains a value for the field "time_space":

```
  time_space: 24:00:00 # doesn't work
```

When I look into my propel.ini (which isn't modified of me so far), I see the following setting:

```
propel.defaultTimeFormat = H:i:s
```

My error message is following when I execute 'symfony propel:data-load' in my CLI:

> Error parsing date/time value:
>   '24:00:00' [wrapped:
>   DateTime::__construct(): Failed to
>   parse time string (24:00:00) at
>   position 0 (2): Unexpected character]

What am I doing wrong? Anyone knows how to set the correct format?
Any help would be very nice, thanks :-)

I'm developing with Windows 7 x64, IIS 7.5, MySQL 5.5.10 and PHP 5.2.17.

Cheers,
Hans Mayer

Comment: Er... does the time "23:59:59" work okay? i.e. is it only when you pass 24 hours you get the problem?

Comment: yes, 23:59:59 works! Where is my thinking wrong? When I try it in phpMyAdmin, I can easily edit 24 hours... Do you know why I can't do it in my fixture? :-)

Comment: @Hans Sorry, I don't know much about Propel; I've only ever used Doctrine, and I've never used the "time" type in either. I was just guessing that the time might be limited to a valid time of day. I don't know whether it's *meant* to be limited, or not... Obviously it's not limited to 24 hours in MySQL, so I guess this is a Propel issue.

Comment: DateTime is a php built-in class, not one belonging to propel.

Comment: @Maerlyn My thinking was just that if putting "24:00:00" in a Propel schema file against a "time" type field breaks the loading of that schema file, then this might be a limitation of the Propel "time" type. Unfortunately I can't seem to find any documentation that says what the minimum and maximum values of Propel's "time" type are, i.e. whether it's meant to only represent times of day, or arbitrary spans of time.

Comment: Maerlyn and Matt, thank you for your help :-) I am now asking myself why there is no clear solution for time periods. I have read the doctrine documentation where it is expicitly told that the time type is for a value of a day. I found nothing in the Propel documentation yet about this. I am now thinking about a workaround solution by using an integer column with a self-made conversion to a time span in my application. But I don't like this by now. I hope someone knows the breaking point or just an alternative solution... :(

Comment: I can't answer my own question, so I have to comment. I got it.
Please excuse my last comment where I wrote "in Doctrine documentation it's explicitly told that the time field is for daytimes". This does not mean that Doctrine doesn't allow higher values. It does!

Seems it will be my first Doctrine project, as with Propel I couldn't realize my time-span.

Using Doctrine as the ORM, I can go above 23:59:59.

But thank you very much for your helps! :-)

Cheers,
Hans Mayer

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you _need_ to use 24:00:00 or higher? Why can't you use 00:00:00?

Comment: @matt There are two different concepts you could store using a "time" type -- there's an "actual time of day" (where 24:00:00 doesn't make a lot of sense, you're right) or there's "time span between two events", where you might want to indicate "this thing happened 37 hours before this other thing", and values greater than 24 are reasonable. MySQL's "time" type is more designed for the latter, and can hold values greater than 24 (+/- around [838 hours](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html)) so it's not unreasonable to think Propel's "time" type might be able to do this, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Doctrine lately (but with timestamp fields) and putting them in '-s solved the problem, so: '23:59:59' would work.

And by the way the 'H' in 'H:i:s' wouldn't let you type 24 because there is no 24. 24 is 00 this time.